# axios, react-native, nodejs on real iOS device gives network errors in Xcode?

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

So I have a node.js server running on my laptop with IP address 73.209.127.93, on port 3000. My react-native app uses axios for HTTP requests, and I am testing it (through Xcode) on my own iPhone, **which is on cell service**. For some reason, when I use the public IP address as the domain, it gives errors like below: 
[image: image of error logs]

I tried using my private IP address (192.168.0.189), and it doesn't work either. It **does** work when my phone is on WiFi, which makes sense.

Here are the permissions I have in the Info.plist (for the public IP address):
[image: permissions]

I change it accordingly when I'm testing the private and public IP address.

**How do I successfully connect and execute HTTP requests with axios on an iPhone on cell service to a nodejs server running on my laptop?**

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not allow HTTP requests by default, If you want to enable HTTP requests edit info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```